# Tensorflow implementation of word2vec

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

The Tensorflow tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/word2vec/index.html#vector-representations-of-words) refers to their basic implementation which you can find on github [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py), where the Tensorflow authors implement word2vec vector embedding training/evaluation with the Skipgram model.

My question is about the actual generation of (target, context) pairs in the `generate_batch()` function.

On [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py#L107) Tensorflow authors randomly sample nearby target indices from the "center" word index in the sliding window of words.

However, they [also keep a data structure `targets_to_avoid`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py#L104) to which they add first the "center" context word (which of course we don't want to sample) but ALSO other words after we add them.

My questions are as follows:

1. Why sample from this sliding window around the word, why not just have a loop and use them all rather than sampling? It seems strange they would worry about performance/memory in `word2vec_basic.py` (their "basic" implementation).
2. Whatever the answer to 1) is, why are they *both* sampling and keeping track of what they've selected with `targets_to_avoid`? If they wanted truly random, they'd use selection with replacement, and if they wanted to ensure they got all the options, they should have just used a loop and gotten them all in the first place!
3. Does the built in [tf.models.embedding.gen_word2vec](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py#L349) work this way too? If so where can I find the source code? (couldn't find the .py file in the Github repo)

Thanks!

Comment: did you find the answer? If so, could you add as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

I tried out your proposed way to generate batches - having a loop and using the whole skip-window. The results are:

**1. Faster generation of batches**

For a batch size of 128 and a skip window of 5

- generating batches by looping over the data one by one takes **0.73s** per 10,000 batches
- generating batches with the tutorial code and `num_skips=2` takes **3.59s** per 10,000 batches

**2. Higher danger of overfitting**

Keeping the rest of the tutorial code as it is, I trained the model with both ways and logged the average loss every 2000 steps:

[image]

This pattern occurred repeatedly. It shows that using 10 samples per word instead of 2 can cause overfitting.

Here is the code that I used for generating the batches. It replaces the tutorial's `generate_batch` function.

```
data_index = 0

def generate_batch(batch_size, skip_window):
    global data_index
    batch = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size), dtype=np.int32)  # Row
    labels = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, 1), dtype=np.int32)  # Column

    # For each word in the data, add the context to the batch and the word to the labels
    batch_index = 0
    while batch_index < batch_size:
        context = data[get_context_indices(data_index, skip_window)]

        # Add the context to the remaining batch space
        remaining_space = min(batch_size - batch_index, len(context))
        batch[batch_index:batch_index + remaining_space] = context[0:remaining_space]
        labels[batch_index:batch_index + remaining_space] = data[data_index]

        # Update the data_index and the batch_index
        batch_index += remaining_space
        data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(data)

    return batch, labels
```

**Edit:** The `get_context_indices` is a simple function, which returns the index slice in the skip_window around data_index. See the [slice() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#slice) for more info.

Comment: what is in the get_context_indices

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @ToussaintLouverture It does answer question number 1. :) Which question are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

There is a parameter named `num_skips` which denotes the number of (input, output) pairs generated from the single window: [skip_window target skip_window]. So `num_skips` restrict the number of context words we would use as output words. And that is why the generate_batch function `assert num_skips <= 2*skip_window`. The code just randomly pick up `num_skip` context words to construct training pairs with target.
But I don't know how `num_skips` affects the performance.